# Angular 6, post file returns 404

Tags: http, post, angular

Хочу создать минимальное хранилище данных с помощью HttpClient в Angular 6. Код на чтение работает. Пример:

```
public constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http.
    get("mytext.json").
    pipe(
      map(x => (<any>x).text)
    ).
    subscribe(txt => this.textToDisplay = txt);
  }
```

В то же время код, который сохраняет значение в файл - возвращает 404.

```
public onSave(): void {
    const opt = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      })
    };
    this.http.post("mytext.json", {text: 'This is from UI!'}, opt).subscribe(
      next => {},
      error => {
        this.errorText = JSON.stringify(error);
      },
      () => {}
    )
  }
```

Пример, пытался повторить вот отсюда https://angular.io/guide/http.

PS: догадываюсь, что сделать REST-бекенд проще, но в данном случае хочу разобраться именно с подобным POST-запросом.

PPS: полный код приложения тут: https://github.com/feliastre/filereader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HttpClient использует HTTP протокол для общения с сервером.

В Случае работы с физическими файлами, вам нужно использовать средства файловой системы.

К примеру если вы хотите сделать хранилище данных в вашем веб приложении, я бы рекомендовал ознакомится с API Filesystem (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystem)

В случае если вы хотите чтобы ваше Веб приложение работало с файлами на серверe, вам прийдется использовать API для работы с файлами на серверной стороне (например Node.js https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html)

В целом, браузер в котором вы запускаете ваше Angualar приложение, не имеет доступа для записи в файлы вас на компьютере.

Если же вы хотите работать с файлами на вашем компьютере из Angular, вы можете попробовать electron.js, в результате у вас будет приложение на angular c возможностью работы с файлами (и не только) на вашем устройстве.